# chromiumembedded mp4 request cancelled

Tags: video, chromium-embedded, off-screen

I'm using CEF in offscreen mode to display web pages in my application.
All the sites and functionality I've tried so far worked fine till I tried video.
Youtube and other sites work fine but I created a small page to autoplay an MP4 and it didn't work.

```
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls autoplay>
   <source src="Some.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> 
</body>
</html>
```

I save the html on local disk and placed the Some.mp4 next to it. When I open the file in Chrome it works fine and the video plays back.

However opening the page in my application via CEF doesn't do anything.
I get the frame for the video and nothing else.
Looking more into the problem in devtools I found that the request for the mp4 files are being canceled.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to legal issues, CEF supports only open source formats. See below link
https://code.google.com/p/cefpython/wiki/AudioVideo

Comment: Thanks, should have checked this out. Doh!